# Consume a Web Service in C#: Remove Task.Wait()

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to consume a web service. It's an XML based service. I mean response in XML format. The code is working fine. However, I do not want to use task.Wait(). Please let me know how I can replace it with async/await.

Below is my code :

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApp6
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program obj = new Program();
        var result = obj.GetData().Result;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetData()
    {
        string url =
            "https://test.net/info.php?akey=abcd&skey=xyz";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
        var responseValue = string.Empty;
        if (response != null)
        {


            Task task = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                var stream = t.Result;
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    responseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            });

            task.Wait(); // How I can replace it and use await


        }

        return responseValue;
    }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Info")]
public class Test
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "att")]
    public string SomeAttribute{ get; set; }
    [XmlText]
    public string SomeText{ get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: Ah - you just do it? Task.await () -> await response.Content.ReadStreamAsync()....

Comment: Watch out for that `.Result` too.

Comment: You are in an async context and you have a task, simply `await` it like so `await task;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already are in an `async` context, so just use `await`:

```
var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    responseValue = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

That said, you should check all your calls:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
```

and make your `main` async, too and while we are at it make the method static:

```
public static async Task Main)
{
    var result = await GetData();
}
```

where your method signature is:

```
public static async Task<string> GetData()
```

The `static` isn't required, but you will find parallel and/or asynchronous programming is a lot easier if you have as little side effects as possible.

Comment: The earlier `.Result` may cause problems if not also addressed.

Comment: @Olivier true, did not see all the instances :)

Comment: Thank you for the quick solution. if is there any good articles for async/await. please reply

Comment: @KiddoDeveloper check out [Stephen Cleary's blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)!

Comment: I don't know any "good" one's, but if I put "async await c#" into google the very first link is the Microsoft documentation that looks like a very solid start.

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html i got this..thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can make [`Main` method `async`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.1/async-main) as well and `await` `GetData`

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Program obj = new Program();
    var result = await obj.GetData();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the sugesstion. I think its a feature of C# 7.0 and am using older version